# Feathersjs - how to create a custom authentication

Tags: authentication, feathersjs

I was wondering if there is a easy way to implement a authentication with custom fields. For ex: My app generate a code that is sent by SMS and I want to authenticate the user with this code. So I can’t use strategy local or anything.

I was thinking about create another service that when the code is received it check the database and generate a JWT token and return to the client app. But how to set that token to the app so it will use in the nexts rest and socket calls?

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the user prior to the generation of code then you can do it via local strategy by saving the generatrd code to that user and use it for authentication. You can also make use of the authentication service hooks. Or in the verifier.

See it here. https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#local-authentication

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the local auth feathersjs provides, there is an additional library supporting all kinds of confirmation procedures, password reset, etc. It is only referenced in the API part of the docs somehow. [Here it is.](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local-management.html)